# how to update package.json after npm installl in a package

Tags: npm

I'm writing a npm package, I'd like the package to update package.json file in the installed folder, say:

npm install mypackage

this installs mypackage, and also read the package.json in the folder where npm install is run, and write some entries, possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
npm i -g npm-check-updates
npm-check-updates -u
npm install
```

or for a specific package, you may change dependency version and then

```
 npm update --save
```